# How do you use 'grep' on this line? Linux

Tags: linux, bash

```
<span class="cur_wind">with 3km/h SSW winds</span><hr class="hr_sm" /></td>
```

I want to extract the words "with 3km/h SSW winds" (note this string will change so hardcoding it wont work) from the line above using the 'grep' command. I have been trying for a long time and am completely lost. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your input is an xml, it would be better to use an xml parser. But if you really want shell scripts, you can use `sed` or `awk`.

Comment: thought so but i dont know how else to do it. any commands that could help me with this? I am new to bash

Comment: @alvits ahhhhh cant use sed or awk unfortunately

Comment: You might want to look at `xmlstarlet` instead.

Comment: Don't parse HTML with regex http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454. But if you so desire, I'll add an answer

Answer (score 2):

Here's a GNU `grep` solution that uses `-P` to activate support for PCREs (Perl-Compatible Regular Expressions):

```
grep -Po '"cur_wind">\K[^<]+' \
  <<<'<span class="cur_wind">with 3km/h SSW winds</span><hr class="hr_sm" /></td>'
```

- `-o` specifies that only the matching string be output
- `\K` is a PCRE-feature that drops everything matched so far; this allows providing context for more specific matching without including that context in the match.

Another option is to use a look-behind assertion in lieu of `\K`:

```
 grep -Po '(?<="cur_wind">)[^<]+' \
  <<<'<span class="cur_wind">with 3km/h SSW winds</span><hr class="hr_sm" /></td>'
```

---

Of course, this kind of matching relies on the specific formatting of the input string (whitespace, single- vs. double-quoting, ordering of attributes, ... - in addition to the fundamental problem of `grep` not understanding the *structure* of the data) and is thus fragile.

Thus, in general, as others have noted, `grep` is the wrong tool for the job.

On **OSX**, assuming the input is XML (or XHTML), you can parse robustly with the stock `xmllint` utility and an XPath expression:

```
xmllint --xpath '//span[@class="cur_wind"]/text()' - <<<\
 '<td><span class="cur_wind">with 3km/h SSW winds</span><hr class="hr_sm" /></td>'
```

---

Here's a similar solution using a **third-party utility**, the [multi-platform web-scraping utility **xidel**](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/xidel.html) (which handles both HTML and XML):

```
xidel -q -e '//span[@class="cur_wind"]' - <<<\
 '<td><span class="cur_wind">with 3km/h SSW winds</span><hr class="hr_sm" /></td>'
```

Comment: This is slick and informative, despite knowing that OP's homework is forcing the OP to use the wrong tool for the job. Nice work +1

Answer (score 1):

Try sed:

```
echo '<span class="cur_wind">with 3km/h SSW winds</span><hr class="hr_sm" /></td>' | sed -e 's/<[^>]*>//g'
```

Output

```
with 3km/h SSW winds
```

**Explanation**

- `echo 'whatever'` will echo the word `whatever` to the screen (stdandard output aka stdout)
- The `|` symbol is a pipe. Command to the right of that will take the output from echo and do something with it
- `sed` is stream editor. It's -e switch tells `sed` to evaluate a script or expression
- `s/xyz/abc/g` format is simple. s/ means substitute. /g means globally. Substitute all occurrences of xyz with abc globally
- `s/<[^>]*>//g` gets interesting. Let's focus on `<[^>]*>`. It means, substitute anything that **starts with <, does not contain > immediately but contains any other character and then has >** with empty
- Check out your `<span class="cur_wind">` for example. That tag starts with <, then contains characters immediately after and then has a >. `sed` says, when such text is found, chop it off (replace with empty)
- Same technique is applied for `<hr>` and `</td>`. What remains is the text you want

This is a somewhat simplified explanation.

Comment: thank you, but this is a part of my homework and i am not allowed to use sed or awk

Comment: @noobcoder, the lecturer who assigns `grep` for extracting content from XML shouldn't have their job. XML is not a regular language, so correctly parsing it with regular expressions (the only method grep has available) is not even theoretically possible. You can write something that's a bad approximation, but it's only ever that -- a bad approximation.

Comment: I do agree with @CharlesDuffy that `grep` shouldn't be the tool to extract data. Grep is for matching/finding...as in...find `ridiculous homework problem` from `profanity.txt` file. And as my previous comment mentioned, HTML shouldn't be parsed with regex

Answer (score 1):

`grep` doesn't know XML, and thus is the wrong tool for the job; use a real XML parser. One of the better ones easily accessible from bash is [XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sf.net/).

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -m "//span[@class='cur_wind']/text()" -v . -n <input.xml
```

This extracts all text directly contained within a span of the class `cur_wind`.

Answer (score 0):

if that is all you want then cat | grep ".*with 3km/h SSW winds.*" should do it, but i suspect there is more then that that you need

Comment: The OP wants to remove the xml tags and just get the values.